# Customize globaltoc & localtoc html rendering

Tags: python-sphinx, tableofcontents

I'm setting up a documentation using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org). I precise I'm really new on this lib.

My documentation can be build with one of the default theme. All works fine :)

Now, I would like to customize the theme. I have updated the `layout.html` to follow my skin. In this template, I include the `globaltoc.html` & `localtoc.html`. The toc is render with `toctree()` & `toc`.

I would like to know if there is a way to update the generated html or if I need to adapt my css to the generated html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and take a guess at what you're looking for - because I think I had the same issue.

As an example, in localtoc.html, the template looks like:

```
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table Of Contents') }}</a></h3>
    {{ toc }}
{%- endif %}
```

`{{ toc }}` is a global macro for Sphinx, and I spent about an hour digging around trying to find where it was defined with absolutely no luck.

The caveat being, `{{ toc }}` renders out to something like:

```
<ul>
   <li>Toc Item 1</li>
   <li>Toc Item 2</li>
   <li>Toc Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The issue being that if your CSS wants to treat `<ul>` or `<li>` tags by class, you have no way of easily changing them. Ultimately I think this is a limitation of Sphinx's writers/html.py, which still does a lot of stuff by hand.

The real solution for this is to replace (possibly builders/html.py), but definitely writers/html.py in Sphinx. Which is a lot more effort than I wanted to expend.

I did manage to find a couple folks who've somewhat addressed this problem, but only partially:

[rst2html5](https://github.com/marianoguerra/rst2html5), which contains an html5css3 HTMLWriter & HTMLTransformer. and [docutils-html5-writer](https://github.com/Kozea/docutils-html5-writer), which, looks really nice - but is not a drop-in replacement for Sphinx due to the difference between builders/html.py and the html5 writer.

Ultimately I came up with this solution, using jinja filters. It's an ugly hack, but it got me past the hurdle.

```
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table Of Contents') }}</a></h3>
   {{ toc|replace("<ul>", "<ul class=\"custom\">", 1) }}
{%- endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's exactly what I'm pointing in my initial issue (you explain it much more better :)). Anyway, I didn't find a "good" solution to the problem...

Comment: Just to clarify, the jinja filtering part is using `{{ toc|replace("<ul>", "<ul class=\"custom\">", 1) }` to effectively do a string replace on the output of `toc`, iirc the actual string replace function in python